# Yii + MySQL error 1064

Tags: mysql, yii

I'm getting the syntax error everytime for this:

```
$skills = SubSkills::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'number DESC','condition'=>'number > 0 AND user_id=:user_id AND select = 0', 'params'=>array(":user_id" =>1),'offset'=>0,'limit'=>2,
));
```

It's fine if I get rid of the `"select = 0`" part.

Here is the error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select < 1 ORDER BY number DESC' at line 1
```

I think it happend because "SELECT" as a row name will conflict with MySQL. Is there a way to escape that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Select is used by SQL. If you are running queries always use backticks for column names:

```
$skills = SubSkills::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'number DESC','condition'=>'number > 0 AND `user_id` = :user_id AND `select` = 0', 'params'=>array(":user_id" =>1),'offset'=>0,'limit'=>2,
));
```

Your solution using double quotes is also a valid solution for solving such conflicts. But I believe using backthicks is more commonly used as it improves readability.

Comment: I think you mean backquote (`) not tilde(~).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the code to

```
$skills = SubSkills::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'number DESC','condition'=>'number > 0 AND user_id=:user_id AND "select" = 0', 'params'=>array(":user_id" =>1),'offset'=>0,'limit'=>2,
));
```

This will bypass the conflict.